# How to identify pin 1 from mechanical design

Tags: datasheet, footprint, packages

Looking at `10142048` [datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7FHTU31_RHT_SENSOR_IC%7F3%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_HTU31_RHT_SENSOR_IC_3.pdf%7F10142048-02) from TE I'm not sure how to identify pin 1 **from top side**.

At page 9 there are the pin assignments from bottom side only.
Now, **I guess**:

- because the side view shows pin 4..6 it means the chip from the bottom view is rotated along the X axis
- if they kept the same rotation pattern for top view, I guess again pin 1 should be in the top-right corner of the top view

Are my assumptions correct?
Even in the recommended footprint there are no indications!

By the way, on pages 9 and 11 there are some references to "notes" 4, 1 and 2 but I really cannot find them. Well, there are on page 2 and 4 but I bet they are related to the tables just above them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the 7th page of [the datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7FHTU31_RHT_SENSOR_IC%7F3%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_HTU31_RHT_SENSOR_IC_3.pdf%7F10142048-02) (the page numbered 6) there is this diagram which should answer all questions:

[image]

Looking at the top side:

Position the chip so the sensor window is near the "top". Pin 1 is then in the lower right-hand corner.

Looking from the bottom:

Pin 1 is closest to the corner which is cut away.

> By the way, on pages 9 and 11 there are some references to "notes" 4, 1 and 2 but I really cannot find them. Well, there are on page 2 and 4 but I bet they are related to the tables just above them.

I can't find any references to any "notes" on either page 9 or 11.

If you are talking about the notes which appear in "Figure 13" on "Page 16":

[image]

then the notes 1 & 2 in the mechanical drawing were not copied to the datasheet, probably because they refer to the dimensions of the tape & reel packaging which follow industry standards.

Comment: Correct for the Table 6. But are you sure that notes 1..4 on page numbered 2 also refer to the remarks in Figure 13?

Comment: "Figure 13" appears on "Page 16". The notes for that mechanical drawing were not copied to to the datasheet. Probably because they refer to the dimensions of the tape and reel packaging which follow industry standards.